# "Publish" tab missing from pages

Tags: office-365, publishing-page, publishing, versioning

I am facing a weird issue. In one of the tenant, the `Publish` tab is missing from the ribbon. Both the publishing features are activated and the versioning setting of pages library is set to `Create major and minor version`.

Besides that, option to change the layout is also not present. It is behaving like web part page more than a publishing page.

Any help.

P.S. I can publish the page by navigating to Pages library.

Comment: Are you sure the page is based on a Publishing page layout, and is not (as you say) a webpart page just living in a Page library?

Comment: yes it is a publishing page. The page layout is attached and I can check in & publish versions from pages library itself.

Comment: Publish in Ribbon or Property?